# What restrictions are there on Cantrips?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, cantrips

This is my first D&D 5th edition campaign, coming from Pathfinder. I'm creating a Bard.

I can't seem to find any restrictions on cantrips. Do I automatically know all of them? Can I cast them an unlimited amount of times?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The details are all in the *Player’s Handbook*.

The table on page 53 lists how many Cantrips Known you have at each level. The corresponding text on page 52 under the Cantrips heading states that these are the only cantrips you know (at least, from the bard class), and that they must come from the bard’s list of 0th-level spells.

But you can cast the ones you do know unlimited times, yes. This is described under Cantrips on page 201. You still must cast them as you would any other spell, however (e.g. spend the appropriate action, cannot do so in armor you aren’t proficient in, etc).

Answer (score 8):

Your class description tells you how many cantrips you get.

Check the table at the beginning of the Bard section to see how you obtain them as you progress. Bards get 2 to start, you choose those off of the Bard cantrip list and know them automatically at the beginning of your career.

You can cast cantrips as often as you want, and their action cost is what they say in the spell description (action, bonus action, etc).

Answer (score 5):

With Tasha's Cauldron of Everything a few new optional rules have been added concerning Cantrips. Basically every full spellcaster class got an optional feature that allows them to exchange their cantrips. Most of them can change the cantrip whenever they get a new ASI/feat, except the wizard. The feature is called differently for the different classes and also allows to exchange some class features, but basically for all full spellcasting classes (except Wizard) it reads as follows:

> Whenever you reach a level in this class that grants the Ability Score Improvement feature, you can replace one cantrip you learned from this class's Spellcasting feature with another cantrip from this class's spell list.

The Wizard has a more powerful feature that allows him to exchange cantrips on long rest, called "Cantrip Formulas":

> You have scribed a set of arcane formulas in your spellbook that you can use to formulate a cantrip in your mind. Whenever you finish a long rest and consult those formulas in your spellbook, you can replace one wizard cantrip you know with another cantrip from the wizard spell list.

Answer (score 0):

I have watched a Bard continually cast Vicious Mockery for an entire combat. It was quite funny, especially since every round the player thought of new insults to the monster.
At the end of the combat, the Bard had mocked one monster to death, and because of the penalties made it a lot harder to for the monsters to inflict damage.

But in essence I can see no reason why a spell caster cannot cantrip every round.  Which is not a bad thing, compared to 1-3rd Ed where the mage sits at the back of the party for the entire battle, unless he chooses to lose his one & only spell for the day.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. This is a cool story, but I’m afraid we’re not a typical discussion forum – we’re a pretty dedicated Q&A site. Among other things, that means we require that answers *answer the question*. Now, you *do* answer the question, but it’s a pretty weak answer: you only state that you see no reason why not. Usually we want answers to be a little stronger than that – we want answerers to “Back It Up!” with something (rules, experience, simulations, whatever). So I suggest expanding your answer a bit. Check out the [Tour] for more about us, and tips on writing great answers.

Comment: ♦: While the quality of this answer may leave something to be desired, it seems better handled with downvotes over removal. Beyond feedback already covered, this answer should also address the concern of "Can I cast them an unlimited amount of times?"